# Convert long to 6 letter hex string

Tags: c, char, hex, data-conversion

I have a long value and I would like to convert it into 6 digit hex string.

My Try:

```
long ID = some value;

char * hex = (char *) calloc(n, sizeof(char)); // dynamic memory required.

int c = sprintf(hex, n+1, "%x", ID);

assert(c == ID);
```

1) how would I find the value of 'n' to give to calloc?

2) how do I make the string only 6 hex characters?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. You can get the size of long variable by using sizeof(long).

2. Not sure why you need to make a string 6 hex characters?

3. When you use char pointer to point a long variable, you need to consider endian.

Comment: The printing function that restricts the buffer size when writing to a string is `snprintf`, not `sprintf`. Pass `n` as second parameter, not `n + 1`. The return value of `snprintf` and the like functions is the number of characters that were written or that would have been written if the buffer were large enough. If you just want to pad a hex string so that numbers with fewer than 6 digits have zeros at the beginning, e.g. `000ff7`, use `"%06lx"`. Larger number will still be written and require a larger buffer.

Comment: the values `long` can hold are from `LONG_MIN` to `LONG_MAX`. Check how many chars `LONG_MIN` needs and use that as your maximum: `int mxlng = snprintf(0, 0, "%lx", LONG_MIN);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of hex digits can be computed like this:

```
int numberOfHexDigits(long ID)
{
    int n=0;
    if (ID==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    while (ID!=0) 
    {
        ID >>= 4;
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Using calloc (or malloc) to allocate memory for just 7 bytes is wasteful. I assume you have a reason to do that.  You are better off just doing this:

```
const int nDigits = 6;
char hex[nDigits+1];
snprintf(hex, sizeof(hex), "%lx", ID);
```

If you *really* want to allocate memory on the heap:

```
int bufSize = numberOfHexDigits(ID)+1;
char *hex = (char *) malloc(bufSize);
snprintf(hex, bufSize, "%lx", ID);
```

Comment: `if (ID==0) {
        return 1;
    }` not needed with `do { ID >>= 4;
        n++;
    } while (ID!=0);`